# What system mail name do I put for Postfix configuration?

Tags: email, postfix, configuration

Following [this](https://ubuntu.tutorials24x7.com/blog/install-mail-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-using-postfix-dovecot-and-roundcube) guide, specifically going to figure 4, what should I put in the dialogue box? My mail subdomain is mail.example.com, but the advice from the dialogue box says that if a mail address on the localhost is foo@example.com, then the correct thing to enter would be example.com I would want a user to have an address like sangstar@example.com, so that makes me feel like I should enter example.com. So which is it -- mail.example.com or example.com? Would entering mail.example.com imply that an email user would be username@mail.example.com? Is this all that's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Please read Postfix's [STANDARD CONFIGURATION README](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html) carefully. Postfix has perfect documentation, it's worth to just dive in it.

I believe they ask for a `myhostname` value in the Postfix config (I wonder, why they never explain which parameter exactly they are setting in these countless how-tos?)

In general, you use a **local hostname**, i.e. whatever `hostname -f` is answering. This name it uses in a banner, in delivery status notifications, in the `Received` header in the email.

For a domain mail to be accepted, you list it in the `mydestination` list. This is the list of domains for which Postfix consider itself a final destination. It will then deliver mail with `local` agent, which is set by `local_transport` parameter.

(There are also virtual domains, but I suspect you don't need them now.)